# Why zend framework can't access to mysql database?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-db, zend-db-table

I'm following the user guide tutorial directly from the Zend framewrok website; I create the  module ALbum and the mysql table as the guide says, but when I open the link 'localhost:8080/album' return a page error with the message below :

> Connect Error: SQLSTATE[42000] [1044] Access denied for user
>   ''@'localhost' to database 'zf2tutorial'

I have also configurated the global.php and local.php as the guide says, in particular I have filled in the local.php this credential :

```
 return array(
     'db' => array(
         'username' => 'root',
         'password' => '',
     ),
 );
```

because the 'zf2tutotial' database was inserted with the root user without password.
Why the framework doesn't access the database ?

Comment: Please check in `application.config.php` that you have written - `'config/autoload/{,*.}{global,local}.php',` The `db` array from `local.php` needs to be merged with the array from `global.php`.

Comment: @KunalDethe Yes, the code is already correct as you say in application.config.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have rights to access database.
Execute

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO ''@localhost
```

and then

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES
```

to get access.

Comment: I have executed that commands from 'mysql -u root'. Great !! Now working ... thx.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your `global.php` file, and match code with the following

```
 return array(
 'db' => array(
     'driver'         => 'Pdo',
     'dsn'            => 'mysql:dbname=zf2tutorial;host=localhost',
     'driver_options' => array(
         PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''
     ),
 ),
 'service_manager' => array(
     'factories' => array(
         'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter'
                 => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory',
     ),
 ),
```

);

and your `local.php` is correct.

Comment: The **global.php** is the same, I resolved it. The problem was the rights to access the database.